# Inserting ssh-agent into i3wm's startup so it's available to all processes in the session

Tags: fedora, xorg, ssh-agent, i3-window-manager

I use the `i3wm` window manager on Fedora, and the `urxvt-mld` terminal dæmon for my multipl `urxvt-mlc` terminal clients.

My problem is that I want just one `ssh-agent` for my entire session, and for the `ssh-agent` to be available to all of the terminal windows, which would most easily be done with

```
ssh-agent urxvt-mld
```

However, I can't figure out where to put that because of all the various files involved in X session and window manager startup.

Should it go in the `i3` config file, read upon `i3wm`'s startup?  The problem I anticipate there is that restarting the window manager might close all the terminals.  (Or might not, if the agent process is detached from the `i3` process tree..)

I don't mind issuing one `ssh-add` command *per* session, but I'd like to be able to do it from any of the terminal windows.  Hence the desire to make them all children of a process that ran `ssh-agent`.

Would a `systemd` user service be appropriate? What would the `wants` and `requires` be for that to get it to happen at the right time?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain). From the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/keychain),

> keychain is a manager for ssh-agent, typically run from ~/.bash_profile. It allows your shells and cron jobs to share a single ssh-agent process. By default, the ssh-agent started by keychain is long-running and will continue to run, even after you have logged out from the system.

I have this line my zsh `~/.zshrc` file:

> eval $(keychain --eval --agents ssh --quick --quiet)